# How to display Redis's Hash value on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am new to Redis and Rails4. I have installed Redis 2.8.4
and 'redis-rails' gem.

I can save hash  and key&value to Redis  and following command works

```
redis.hset(cartid, prodductid ,20)
```

If I go to Redis, I can see the value

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> hscan "cart_b342b01837edd4073cab312e93864b3a" 0
    1) "0"
    2) 1) "product_1"
       2) "20"
       3) "product_5"
       4) "20"
       5) "product_2"
       6) "20"
       7) "product_3"
       8) "20"
```

Now, I want to get the values in controller. So I wrote,

```
 @cartitems= redis.hscan(cartid,0)
```

It does not work. If I try to debug

```
raise @cartitems=redis.hscan(cartid,0)
```

Or

```
  raise @cartitems=redis.hgetall(cartid)
```

it gives following error

> exception class/object expected

Hope it is clear. Not sure, how to display the output from Redis?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was working. However, my debug code was wrong.
It would be

`raise @cartitems.inspect`

Hope, it will help someone.